# How can I open a new terminal window from a cli command and print "Hello World"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I've been playing with the gnome-terminal command for some minor automations, and I keep running into the same issue. The goal is to open a new window in the same directory as the current window, and execute a simple command (i.e. echo, cd, or similar). This command seems to work fine to open the new window in the same directory:

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR
```

However, when I add an execution to it, it fails:

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -e 'echo "test"'
```

I receive a message saying that `-e` is deprecated and I should use `--` so I swapped to

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- 'echo "test"'
```

However I now receive this error:

`Failed to execute child process “echo "test"” (No such file or directory)`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Exact System Specs:
Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME Terminal 3.32.1 using VTE 0.56.2 +GNUTLS

The exact deprecation message is:

`# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.`

```
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the deprecation warning? Also, what version of `gnome-terminal` are you using?

Comment: Hi barton, thanks for your feedback. I've updated the question with the information you asked for. Let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I see. The two messages are actually distinct.

```
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
```

I think this means that you should use `-x`, instead -- everything on the command line  after `-x` is considered to be part of the command to be executed.

```
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

This is a convention used in command line programs. The two dashes indicate that anything that comes afterward, regardless of whether or not it has a dash, is *not* a command line option. It's *useful* in conjunction with `-x`, because you may have stuff that you don't want parsed as one of the options to gnome-terminal -- rather they're command line arguments to be run *inside* the terminal.

I think an example would probably make this clearer...

```
gnome-terminal -x -- grep -v "42" hitchikers_guide_to_the_galaxy.txt
```

This opens a gnome terminal. Inside the terminal we're running grep, and excluding any line that contains the string "42". If we had not used `--`, gnome-terminal would see `-v` as a command line argument of `gnome-terminal`, and probably thrown a warning saying that `-v` is not a valid argument to gnome-terminal.

Edit:

Ok, so both `-x` and `-c` are deprecated. You *can* execute commands without  any flags. It does require using `--` to terminate all other options... so I was pretty much wrong about everything that I said. The rationale was solid, just wrong.

```
gnome-terminal -- nano
```

will open a new terminal, and launch nano inside the terminal.

Things get tricky when you try

```
gnome-terminal -- echo foo
```

It runs, but it exits so fast that you don't see anything other than a flash on the screen.

Note that there is also an open bug about the deprecation of `-c`:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784925

Comment: I got really excited reading this as it seems to make a lot of sense the way you describe it, but I still get an error:
```DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -x -- echo "test"
# Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’```

Comment: Hmm.. Re: Edit, I see what you mean. Womp womp. even gnome-terminal -- ls seems to break it

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the issues in the OP, 2 Points:

1. For

   ```
   DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- 'echo "test"'
   ```

the (unexplained) error indicates that the "command" is

```
echo "test"
```

i.e. it is trying to run the program stored in the file named `echo "test"` (being the single argument after the --). The correct syntax would be

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- echo "test"
```

(no 's)

but (as stated by Barton Chittenden) that then results in the terminal window appearing and disappearing (after executing the echo) almost instantly (probably faster than the screen refresh rate, giving the appearance that nothing happened). It needs some delay. So try

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- echo "test" ; sleep 5
```

(I know this is wrong, wait for the analysis)

but this just seems to do nothing for longer. Reason:- `;` is a reserved symbol (control operator) and terminates the argument list for `gnome-terminal`. The `sleep 5` is a separate command executed after the (do nothing) `gnome-terminal`. Trying to quote the ; is ineffective:

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- echo "test" \; sleep 5
```

This is syntactically valid if what you want is to display **test ; sleep 5** in a nanosecond window. No, the problem here is that we are trying to execute a command **LIST** not a command (single executable). So the answer is:

2. Execute a general command line in a new window using "sh -c":

   ```
   DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- sh -c 'echo "test" ; sleep 5'
   ```

or maybe

```
DIR=$(pwd); gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR -- sh -c 'echo "test" ; echo Press ENTER to continue ; read a'
```

P.S. For the pedants, I know that spaces around ; and the " around (the single word) test are unnecessary. Also, I have used the generic `sh` to represent whichever version is in use on the target system (and assumed that `-c` works as in Bourne shell). Further, the shell variable (`DIR` in the example) is redundant, just use `--working-directory=$(pwd)`, unless you want to use the value again within the subsequent command (line). In fact, in my testing, `gnome-terminal` starts in the current directory of the invoking process, so `--working-directory` is almost certainly redundant here. Finally, the question wanted to print "Hello World", so the (fully and minimally) correct answer (with added delay) is:

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo Hello World;sleep 5'
```

P.P.S. While testing the (deprecated) `-e` and `-x` options, the following was noted (V3.28.2):

- `-x` has the same effect as `--`, further argument processing is still inhibited. This possibly explains the "odd" error

  ```
  #_g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
  ```

as it is trying to execute the command `--`. (Didn't get this exact error in my testing, just the standard `"--" No such file or directory`.)

- `-e` invokes its argument as a command line **BUT** not as sh(1) input. The argument is parsed into *words* at white-space boundaries (tested space, tab and newline), allowing \ (quote single character including white-space) and both " and ' (quote enclosed string, no observed difference). The first *word* is the command name. It must be a path to an executable file (absolute, relative or `$PATH` findable), **NOT** a shell only built-in (e.g. `read`, `cd` vs. shell built-ins that have a corresponding external binary, e.g. `echo`, `sleep`). The command is invoked using the remaining *words* as arguments (probably using `exec(3)` since `system(3)` would recognise shell syntax). `-e` overrides any other command invocation options, i.e. `--`, `-x`.